# unexpected token setState to object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set state to an object, so I do

```
    const user = this.state.user;
    this.setState({
      user['id']: 123 //error here
    });
```

I got unexpected token error, I also tried `user.id` and `user[id]`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are anyways copying the state to a separate variable, you can just modify the object and then set it to state

```
const user = {...this.state.user};
user['id'] = 123
this.setState({
   user
});
```

You way doesn't work because you cannot just directly assign a nested object a value using `setState`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want to change `id`, but still keeping the other property of `user`. You can do something like this.

```
const user = this.state.user;
this.setState({
    user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        id: 123
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid syntax for initializing an object. User is an object, and id is a property on that object. Use `setState` like this:

```
const user = this.state.user;
this.setState({
    user: {
        id: 123
    }
});
```

See [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more information on working with objects in javascript.